Swift - Time Consuming Processing of an Array
I am trying to process over an array of simple elements, where on every element of the array a time-consuming process of updating the UI with a Timer will be started. The order of the elements in the array is important and matters. For simplicity sake I simplified the code down to this:
func processArray() {
    let signals = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
        
    for element in signals {
        //pause and process first element
        timeConsumingProcess(e: element)
            
        //after processing first element finished, continue to next element
    }
}
    
func timeConsumingProcess(e: Int) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { timer in
        // 2 seconds set for demonstration purposes, can take more or less depending on the element
        // doing something with e in UI
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

How can I pause array iteration while the time consuming timeConsumingProcess(e: Int) is happening?I tried using OperationQueues, DispatchGroups, DispatchSerialQueues, sync{} blocks, but to no avail. I'm guessing with the advancement of Swift concurrency and Async/Await there should be an elegant and efficient solution to it, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Sequentially processing time-consuming events has never been easy in Swift, but I'm entirely at a loss here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Elements normally process one at a time, so your desired behavior is the default behavior. The reason your code example seems to be processed in parallel is because your timeConsumingProcess is asynchronous. Is your actual long running task also asynchronous?

Yes, it does a number of UI updates that are triggered by timers (think flashing LEDs), which is why it matters to stop array iteration while UI updates corresponding to every element are not carried out. I thought of building a sequence of UI update functions and then executing them synchronously, but it didn't work for me with DispatchGroups, OperationQueues and other synchronous approaches, I couldn't build a pre-defined sequence of tasks that need to happen in order based on the array element.

Just write your own function that goes through the array one by one doing what needs to be done on each iteration. This function will likely not make use of the for-in loop. Always think as simply as possible. Code it like a caveman would--grab element 0, do something, when done check if array has element at 0 + 1, do something, when done check if array has element at 0 + 2, etc.

You can use async-await to achieve this. Something like this should work. Where the print is the place to make your UI changes. (you'll need to DispatchQueue.main.async any UI Changes)
let array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Task {
    for item in array {
        await doAThing(item)
    }
}


func doAThing(_ item: Int) async {
    print("\(item)")
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
}


If you can't use async await due to lower api support, you can use DispatchQueue.asyncAfter like so:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (2 * arrayIndex)) {
    // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here
}

With this you won't use a for loop but instead you'll need a DispatchQueue.asyncAfter for each item in your array and it'll handle it's own logic.

It worked with one small change! Please change var array to let array so I could accept it as the answer. Otherwise there's an error Reference to captured var 'array' in concurrently-executing code

Glad it worked, have updated the answer.
